# Counter only adds once

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a simple hangman game that has a Jlabel that is supposed to show how many times the word was guessed right. It uses a simple counter wins++ and will show up properly after the first win but any after won't work. The counter won't add more so do I need to use a loop in some way?

```
if (word.equals(dashes.toString()))
{   
     wordOutput.setText("You Win!");
     wins++; //add 1 to win counter
     winsOutput.setText("Wins: " + wins);
}
```

Seems like this should be simple but I don't know what's wrong

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Probably you gave defined `wins` locally, like `int wins = 0;` before you check the above condition.

Comment: I suggest to start to debug code in your favourite `IDE`.

Comment: I agree with forpas, that's the most likely reason for this. Of course we can't know for sure unless OP gives us more code.

Comment: farpas was right and it worked now! Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you made the **win** variable as a local, which will get its initial stage after every execution, make the win variable outside of the method and you can also make it **static**.

```
public class Hangman {
   // here is the variable..
   private int wins = 0;

   // Here are your other methods..
   public void processGame(){
   }

}
```

By the way, it will also works fine without **static** if your game does not have more than one classes etc. Give it a try with static and without it, but the main point is initializing it outside of the class.

Comment: You shouldn't really post an answer based on guesswork. There are a ton of ways his code could be wrong.

Comment: You are right, but it is the most common reason which makes his result wrong according to his statement.

Comment: You got lucky there, lad. ;)

Comment: Hahaha.. Yeah :)